# AutoIt won't send number to browser

Tags: browser, numbers, send, autoit

I have a small script to auto-input data into a website after clicking some buttons to get to the inputboxes

Here the snippet that won't work:

```
$findButton = _ImageSearch('pioTextbox.bmp', 0, $x, $y, 0)
    if $findButton Then
        MouseMove($x + 10, $y + 10)
        Sleep(500)
        MouseClick("left")
        Send("{9}")
        Sleep(1500)
```

It successfully finds the input boxe and clicks, but simply doesn't send '9'

Note: The textbox only allows digits(just numbers)

I tried using {Numpad9} but with no difference.

Thanks for any ideas of how to send numbers where only digits are allowed

This is using firefox also, but I can use any browser

Comment: Why would you use {9} ? Use Send("9")

Comment: Because it wasnt working so I changed it to {9}, yes it works with '9' now :P

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it suddenly started working, I changed something completely different and now its working with Send("{9}")

Thanks